# Upload snapshot from webcam directly to twitpic, flickr, facebook

Tags: flash, facebook, flickr, twitpic

I succeed to get a snapshot from the webcam as a jpeg (via BitmapArray) and now I want to upload it **directly** to twitpic or flickr . Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: For facebook, check out this guide: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/